# Stack Exchange Android app doesn't display LaTex correctly

Tags: bug, android-app

Why doesn't the Stack Exchange Android app display LaTeX as mathematical formulas correctly instead of just showing the LaTeX code ? It just shows the Raw LaTeX code which doesn't help when trying to read the mathematical formulas...

Comment: Yeap thanks you pointed this out